# Slickgrid - Wordwrap column headers in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

is there a way to word-wrap Slickgrid column headers in IE7? I have about 20+ 
columns in the grid - and almost all columns have 2 or more words.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by editing 2 css tags:

In `slick-default-theme.css`:

```
.slick-header-columns {
    white-space: pre !important;
    height: 45px;
}
```

The `height` here is adjustable to your needs. This was good to display 3 lines.

In `slick.grid.css`, change the `height` settings on the below tag to `100%`:

```
.slick-header-column.ui-state-default {
    ...
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfect!!!

```
.slick-header-columns {
    white-space: pre !important;
    height:100%;
}
```

If two grids are created and only one of them has got long header text.